# How to retrieve QML camera feed and send to C++ backend

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qml

I am trying different implementations of how to achieve further processing from the QML camera, I need to pass on the feed to the C++ end so it can then be converted to a cv::Mat image and passed to a function for processing. I have tried setting a QCamera from the C++ end and starting it on a button click but it seems Qt cannot create two instances of the same camera. I have also tried an open CV method but to no avail. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Capturing an image and processing it is not an option? Once you have saved the image it can be used with `imread` to generate a `Mat` object for processing.

Comment: I need to have the feed running continuously in the backend. If I could get an implementation where a QImage can be continuously generated from the feed from the QML end  and sent back to my opencv function I have solved the issue.

Comment: You can capture continuously by issuing a capture as soon as you have captured an image. Wouldn't be better to capture a new image as soon as you have processed the previous one? Sorry for the questioning, I would like to perfectly understand your needs.

Comment: Camera{
            id: cam
            imageProcessing.whiteBalanceMode: CameraImageProcessing.WhiteBalanceFlash

            captureMode: Camera.CaptureStillImage
            objectName: "Camera"
            imageCapture{
                onImageCaptured: {
                    camfeed.source = preview
                    wrapper.processImage(preview)
                }
            } 
This is my implementation so far on the camera, I understand what you're saying so after an image is change (onImageCaptureChanged)? emit a signal to C++?

Comment: When the processing is terminated you emit a signal from c++ and handle it in QML. In the handler you call a new capture and you closed the circle. Is it OK like that?

Comment: Basically I was thinking to something like [this](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=FFbMUnnD) where `wrapper` is a context property which emits `processingTerminated` when image has been processed. After you started the capturing with the `MouseArea`, capturing - and processing - goes on forever. if you need to show the captured image you can define a second feed but the camera stays unique.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, I already had my wrapper class set up via context property so making this was fairly easy, I have now come across another problem though, I am not doing the processing via Mouse area it is on a button click so: OnClicked: cam.imagecapture.capture() and in the C++ backend it is not recieiving an image, any ideas?

Comment: That should not male (almost ABY) differenze. I'll provide an answer for that.

Comment: I displayed the image in a preview, but it is a still image taken of initialisation of the camera. Will it need a timer to update the image as it changes?

Comment: AFAIK You don't need a timer for that. I can't try that right now.

Answer (score 3):

This is a not a fix but a workaround. I used an OpenCv plugin for the camera and made it visible to my QML using qmlRegisterType. I could then easily send the frames from the backend to my other class for processing. For anyone looking to do this I used this plugin: https://github.com/rferrazz/CvCamView

Comment: Oh you solved the issue. Good. I was in the process to review the code I had provided. Well, I'm glad you've  found a viable solution. :)

Comment: Thankyou for the help anyway. I do think it would certainly be worthwhile for there to be an example of actually grabbing the frames directly from the QML camera though.. While putting the CVcamera directly as an element on QML was a good fix, it took away the aesthetically pleasing factor that QML had..

Answer (score 2):

[Qt QML Camera to C++ QImage on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28041741/qt-qml-camera-to-c-qimage-on-android/33238150#33238150)

I just answered this question, I think you were having the same issue.

The basic Idea here is to get the instance of QML camera, access its QMediaObject point and probe it with QVideoProbe. There are other solutions, but AFAIK they arent really easy or fast in Android platforms, but if thats not your case, you probavly should try QAbstractVideoFilter alongside QVideoFilterRunnable classes which were developed specially for post processing qml video feed.

Note that QAbstractVideoFilter  and QVideoFilterRunnable are Qt 5.5 classes only.