# QML camera item missing from rootObject->childItems

Tags: android, c++, qt, camera, qml

I am working on a face recognition app on Android with Qt. I have a QtQuickWidget in my ui; managed to get QtQuick camera working; but not able to get frames in C++.

I tried the answer [Qt QML Camera to C++ QImage on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28041741/qt-qml-camera-to-c-qimage-on-android/33238150), which looks like 'the solution' for the issue BUT: ui->quickWidget->rootObject()->childItems() doesn't have camera item.. it has all the other items (button1, vf). So findChild is failing.

Request to throw some light into this. Thanks in advance.
QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtMultimedia 5.5

Item {
    id: camvf

    Camera {
        id: cam
        objectName: "cam"
    }


    VideoOutput {
        id: vf
        objectName: "vf"
        source: cam
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height-100
        anchors.top: parent.top
        focus : visible // to receive focus and capture key events when visible
        autoOrientation: true
    }


    Rectangle {
        id: button1
        objectName: "button1"
        anchors.top:vf.bottom
        width: parent.width
        height: 100
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `Camera`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-camera.html) states that it's derived from `QtObject`, which means that `childItems()` won't include it, because it's not a visual type. You need to use `QObject::children()` instead.

The [Concepts - Visual Parent in Qt Quick](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-visualcanvas-visualparent.html) documentation explains how all of this works:

> The concept of the visual parent in Qt Quick is separate from, but related to, the concept of the object parent within the QObject parent hierarchy. All QML objects have an object parent, which is determined by the object hierarchy in which the object is declared. When working with the QtQuick module, the Item type is the base type for all visual items provided by this module, and it provides the concept of an additional visual parent, as defined by an item's parent property. Every item has a visual parent; if an item's parent property value is null, the item will not be rendered in the scene.
>
> Any object assigned to an item's data property becomes a child of the item within its QObject hierarchy, for memory management purposes. Additionally, if an object added to the data property is of the Item type, it is also assigned to the Item::children property and becomes a child of the item within the visual scene hierarchy. (Most Qt Quick hierarchy crawling algorithms, especially the rendering algorithms, only consider the visual parent hierarchy.)

If you're curious, [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/src/quick/items/qquickitem.cpp#n3151) is the point in Qt's source code where the addition of children to an `Item` is handled.

Comment: Thank you for the info.  rootObject()->children() gave me cam also..

Still.. findChild("cam") is not returning anything.. for the same reason you have mentioned I assume. Will try some stunt to get hold of it..

Bit baffled how the solution in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28041741/qt-qml-camera-to-c-qimage-on-android/33238150 worked for some..(I fully understand that you do not have any obligation to explain someone else's answer.. still some info on this would be appreciated.)

Comment: Ah.. got the issue.  I was trying to cast findChild("cam") to QQuickItem rather than QObject.. Your link gave me insight into the issue. Thank you.