# How use Camera in Android and Desktop with Qt

Tags: android, c++, qt, camera, qml

I would like to display and get frame of Camera on my Qt robot project who use QWidgets/C++, on Desktop and Android.
Camera work in programs with only QML but my actual project need to use QWidgets in C++.

I tried various way :

1. QQuickView with containers to display QML Camera don't work Android
2. I tried this : [Qt QML Camera to C++ QImage on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28041741/qt-qml-camera-to-c-qimage-on-android/33238150#33238150) 
   But I don't get frame.
3. I also saw this : http://www.programering.com/a/MTN3IjMwATQ.html / 
   http://blog.csdn.net/kl222/article/details/23187693
   But It's not work with Android

Comment: Qt widgets camera example: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimediawidgets-camera-example.html

Comment: It doesn't work on Android (Camera won't start and crash)

Comment: I'm afraid but that's simply not possible with widgets see [QTBUG-35243](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-35243). The rest of the question is a bit too vague to be answered.

Comment: To be more specific : how can I get frame from Camera on Android ? According to the links I posted it's seems possible. QCamera don't work and Android but maybe I can get frame from QML and import in "C++", convert and process to QImage to display on QWidget

Comment: As @BaCaRoZzo said there is no way to do this using widgets. I would try something similar to what you said - embed simple QML scene into your widget project.

Comment: The QML solution you have linked should work fine. If you have encountered problems implementing it it would be better to have a specific question for that.

Comment: If I use methode of "way n°2" : setprobe return false on windows. Return true on Android but slot handleFrame is never called, see my [QT project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/17zv20fw4fyyfj4/AABqsNRu6L3Jf-d1eDoLpRmna?dl=0)

Comment: EDIT : If I use methode of "way n°3" : (QAbstractVideoSurface subclass) : slots work only with QCamera *cam=new QCamera, but no with Camera cast from QML, so It don't work on Android, you can see my project with this methode [QT project example2](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/00w7st1u1wjlb7p/AADYtdhSwsNaW_dPs5eEezANa?dl=0)

Comment: By using dynamique allocation (new) on : QQmlApplicationEngine or QQuickview, QML camera work on Windows. So : I can get Camera frame from QML Camera to C++ on Windows, but It don't work on Android (Slots are never exectuded) [QT project example3](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sevn9ngtwp4wmtz/AABHgWIc4VwMwTy7X-M-LF_Da?dl=0)

Comment: Stack objects are gone when the function is exited. That's a major problem in (all) your code. And that's also something that must be crystal clear if you play around with unmanaged code, like in C++.

Comment: I was thinking that when Camera is casted, I didn't need QmlApplicationEngine that's why I didn't use dynamic memory. It's working on desktop, do you know how can I make it work on Android ?

Comment: I was talking about the `probe` in the first example. Possibly the same applies to the `QQmlApplicationEngine`, indeed. I've implemented a `QVideoProbe`-derived class to be used with a full QML application. Can't say for sure about your specific setting. As a first step, review your object lifetime.

Comment: I reviewed lifetime on the VideoProbe project QT project example4. setSource on Android return true but always this problem : slot is never executed. I tried on other Android device (With Android 4.4 and 5.1) same result : slot is never executed.

Comment: So, I tried to use [video filters in QT 5.5](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2015/03/20/introducing-video-filters-in-qt-multimedia/). I created [this project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/osi2v1v9i4rwjh9/AADyqpdTwpcOu_e-Nr7pSat3a?dl=0) : it seems that this time they are frames : "run" fonction in MyFilterRunnable class is called. My question is how can I get these frames in my QMainWindow class ? I think I need to use signal/Slot but I don't really know how do that. To convert and display in second time (recall that my goal is to get frame from QML and display to C).

Comment: I can get and convert frame in Qimage on windows now but on Android :  frame format return 0 => QVideoFrame::Format_Invalid. Does it means that frames don't work or it's only a unknown format ?

Answer (score 6):

I find a answer to my problem (The goal is to get frame from camera and display on QWidget on Android and Windows)

First in QML : get a camera and filter :

```
Item {
    signal submitFrame(var img)//used to send QImage to C++ after filter process

    Camera {
        id: camera
    }
    MyFilter {
        id: filter
        onFinished: submitFrame(result)
    }
    VideoOutput {
        source: camera
        filters: [ filter ]
    }
}
```

QAbstractVideoFilter subclass :

```
class MyFilter : public QAbstractVideoFilter
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyFilter();

    QVideoFilterRunnable *createFilterRunnable();

signals:
    void finished(const QVariant& result); //send QImage got to QML

public slots:
};
```

QVideoFilterRunnable subclass :

```
class MyFilterRunnable : public QVideoFilterRunnable
{
public:
    MyFilterRunnable(MyFilter *filter);
    ~MyFilterRunnable();

    QVideoFrame run(QVideoFrame *input, const QVideoSurfaceFormat &surfaceFormat, RunFlags flags) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

private:
    MyFilter *m_filter;
};
```

Process frame (Convert QVideoframe to QImage)

```
QVideoFrame run(QVideoFrame *input, const QVideoSurfaceFormat &surfaceFormat, RunFlags flags) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

//On Android
if(frame->handleType() == QAbstractVideoBuffer::GLTextureHandle){
    /*        ...

    Need treatment with OpenGL or other to "convert" frame to QImage.
    see here : http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtmultimedia.git/tree/examples/multimedia/video/qmlvideofilter_opencl in file rgbframehelper.h

    ...    */

    emit m_filter->finished(QVariant (imgToDisplay));// send QImage got to QML
}
//On Windows
else{
    //easy convert VideoFrame to QImage
    QImage::Format format = VideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(frame->pixelFormat());
    if (fmt != QImage::Format_Invalid){
        QImage img=QImage(frame->bits(), frame->width(), frame->height(), format);
        QImage imgToDisplay = img.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB888);
        emit m_filter->finished(QVariant(imgToDisplay));// send QImage got to QML
    }
}
```

Now on C++, MainWindow  :

```
qmlRegisterType<MyFilter>("my.uri", 1, 0, "MyFilter");
//load QML
QQuickView *view=new QQuickView();
view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///main.qml"));
view->show();

//connect to get QImage as QVariant from QML to this C++ class
QObject *topLevel =view->rootObject();
QObject::connect(topLevel, SIGNAL(submitFrame(const QVariant &)),this, SLOT(handleFrame(const QVariant &)));
```

And display slot :

```
void MainWindow::handleFrame(const QVariant &in)
{
    //cast Qvariant =>QImage
    QImage image = in.value<QImage>();

    // QImage to QPixmap for display
    ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    ui->label->resize(image.size());
    ui->label->update();
}
```

To summarize : QML camera "send" frames to c++ filter. Filter convert frames to QImage and send these QImage to QML as QVariant. From C++ display class, get QVariant with connect and cast to QImage for display on QWidget.

It's certainly not the best way (Android convert frame to QImage is too slow and maybe to much exanche with QML and C++) but It sufficient for my project (I get ~15 fps).

If someone has a better idea, please do share.